# Reactive State function unit testing in vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I am very new to unit testing. I have reactive state usage in the component. would like to write unit testing for the component.

The example test component is defined below

```
 <script setup lang="ts">
 const state = reactive({ 
  isExpired: true as boolean, 
 })
 </script>
<template>
    <div class="container" v-if="state.isExpired === false"></div>
</template>
```

Here, I want to check whether the container is rendering or not. isExpired value will be dynamically changed.

I have tried the test cases for the component as shared below

```
describe("Test suit for component",()=>{
   let wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent,{
     isExpired : false
   });
   it("its should display container style",async ()=>{ 
      expect(wrapper.find('.container').exists()).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

I am not able to find the relevant unit testing in the online resources. Would like to know how to test the reactive state of component.

Comment: `{
     isExpired : false
   }` doesn't make sense. The property is defined inside the comp. You need to change it outside, like `wrapper.vm.isExpired=`

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes I have tried your suggestion. It's not working.  still is failing. 

 it("its should display container style",async ()=>{
        wrapper.vm.isExpired = false;
        expect(wrapper.find('.container').isVisible());
    })

Comment: Likely this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751635/vue-test-utils-using-nexttick-multiple-times-in-a-single-test

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set the state value after mounting the component

```js
describe("Test suit for component",()=>{
   let wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent, { /* in here you would set the component input props*/});

   wrapper.vm.state.isExpired = false; // <- we modify ViewModel state value

   it("its should display container style",async ()=>{ 
      expect(wrapper.find('.container').exists()).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```